# Crafter 3 Gradle bundle error

Tags: gradle, crafter-cms

I am using Crafter 3.0.2 and trying to create deployable bundles through the gradle tooling provided by the [craftercms project](https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms).

When executing `gradlew build deploy bundle -Pcrafter.profile=true`, I received the error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 774

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':zipauthoring'.
> archive's size exceeds the limit of 4GByte.
```

The gradle suggestion following the error above is to enable zip64. So I added `zip64 true` to the build.gradle pack method's `tasks.create("zip${envName}", Zip.class) {`, and the bundle task completed successfully.

However, this approach seemed a little invasive. What is the proper procedure for producing a Crafter 3 bundle with profile enabled? If zip64 is to be used for the authoring bundle, is there a command line option that can be provided instead of editing build.gradle? Alternatively, is there a mechanism for creating only the tar.gz archive (which does not appear to have the 4gb file limitation) instead of the zip archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ticket now to allow the users to select the bundle they want: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1669

I've never seen a bundle exceed 600MB, you're pushing up against 4GB which is very unusual. While adding 64bit will help it push on, there might be another issue at play here.

Comment: Thank you. I discovered the bundle I was creating was also including my local state, which included video binaries. Going forward, I will remove extraneous web server or any other state before creating bundles.

Comment: That makes sense , you could use `-Pauthoring.root=crafter-auth-clean/ -Pdelivery.root=crafter-dev-clean/ ` to create a paralle enviroment with out you videos (but also with out any sites)